# gsub in R with case condition in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have data like : PES + PEA + PWH

I want to use gsub or any other function in R such that --
if there is a PEA in the data then keep PEA (and PWH should be kept too) and remove just PES

So ideally the condition should involve only PEA and PES.

Final Output : PEA + + PWH
Thanks!

Comment: If `x <- "PES + PEA + PWH"`, is this what you mean? `ifelse(grepl("PEA", x), gsub("PES", "", x), x)`

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I think your logic works for me thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question would be easier to answer if you could provide a sample data set. Assuming that your intention is to replace certain strings taking into account capitals the `ignore.case = FALSE` should be enough. For example:

```
x <- "PES + PEA + PWH + pes"
gsub("PES","New text",x, ignore.case = FALSE)
```

would give you:

```
[1] "New text + PEA + PWH + pes"
```